# JPA: Existing Entity not updated

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, stateless

I am facing a problem where in some very rare cases (<1%) an existing entity is not updated correctly. In all other cases it is working as expected.

Stack: JPA & Hibernate, Wildfly10 (Cluster), Ubuntu, PostgreSQL (Master/Slave Setup)

What is happening?

1. A user is waiting in his browser that the ContractEntity is set to `PAID`. The browser is doing a request every 3 seconds pulling the status of the ContractEntity
2. Our payment provider is calling a webhook on our server, which calls the function `setContractToPaidAndNotifyUsers()`. This should change the status of the ContractEntity to `PAID`, but it stays at status `STARTED`. There are no errors logged and the other function calls that happen afterwards work correctly (sending out emails).

So I assume that error is happening when the database transaction is committed.

This is the function that the webhook calls:

```
@Stateless
public class ContractBoundary {

    @Inject
    private ContractControl contractControl;


    private void setContractToPaidAndNotifyUsers(PaymentEntity paymentEntity, ContractEntity contractEntity, final String paidResourceId) {

        // This is not working (no error, but the contract remains on status STARTED
        contractEntity.setStatus(ContractStatusEnum.PAID);
        contractEntity.setPaidResourceId(paidResourceId);
        ContractEntity updatedContractEntity = contractControl.update(contractEntity);

        // These are working
        mailControl.sendMoneyArrivedMailToPayee(
                contractBoundary.getContractLink(updatedContractEntity.getContractCode()),
                updatedContractEntity.getTitle(), updatedContractEntity.getPayer(), updatedContractEntity.getPayee(),
                eventMoneyArrivedForPayee);
        mailControl.sendMoneyArrivedMailToPayer(
                contractBoundary.getContractLink(updatedContractEntity.getContractCode()), contractEntity.getTitle(),
                updatedContractEntity.getPayer(), updatedContractEntity.getPayee(), eventMoneyArrivedForPayer);


        }
}
```

This is the update fuction in `contractControl`

```
public class ContractControl extends BasicCrudControl {

    // ... more CRUD functions

    public ContractEntity update(final ContractEntity contract) {
        ContractEntity update = super.update(contract);
        return update;
    }
}
```

This is the update-function of our BasicCRUDControl:

```
protected <T> T update(final T entityToUpdate) {
    T t = this.em.merge(entityToUpdate);
    return t;
}
```

Do I have to run `em.flush();` or `em.refresh();` in my `update` function?
Because it is only happening in some cases, I think that there might be a problem when the request from the users browser is executed at the same time as the webhook is called, which may lead to some troubles.

Also, I just recognized that the `ContractControl` does not have a `@Stateless` Annotation, can this lead to problems as `ContractBoundary` is marked as stateless and is injecting `ContractControl`?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the value in the returned 'updatedContractEntity' correct when sending the Mail (getContractCode()?) , e.g. updated but not commited?

Comment: Yes, the status is correctly set to `PAID` at this point. However, if I recall it correctly (the developers who build up the CRUD control told me) all transaction commits happen once the request is done. If there is an exception during the request, the transaction is rolled back. But I might be wrong here. Also, as this is happening only in some rare cases it is really hard to debug. I was not able to create this error on my local environment

Comment: Is there anything else manipulating ContractEntity? My guess would be that the code works reliably 100% of the time, but occasionally another process winds up reading the old value then overwriting the change you just made with an outdated value.

Comment: There is a fullfilment-scheduler running every minute. But this scheduler is only pulling contracts with status 'PAID' and depends on some other values as well, which all are not true for the contracts mentioned

Comment: I have an event entity which is created/updated after the status change of the contract. The event entity is referencing the contractentity with @ManyToOne annotations and the contract is referencing a list of events with @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contract", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY). Maybe this leads to problems?

Comment: Is this event entity created in an entity listener? Also, is it possible that the transaction is rejected after all the processing is done but before the request ends? Did you check the logs? The 'fullfilment-scheduler' might simply be causing a deadlock between the two transactions (what is the transaction isolation level?)

Comment: @crizzis no, the event is created via an controller (which uses em.persist()). I dont think that the whole transaction is rejected, because all other entities that are created/updated are commited, it is just the contractEntity where the problem occurs. I do not know exactly about the isolation level (where can I check this?), but transaction-type is JTA and all entites extend our basic entity that looks like this: `@XmlRootElement
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners({ CreatedAtListener.class, UpdatedAtListener.class })
public class BasicEntity implements Serializable { ... }`

Comment: @crizzis isolation level on our postgres database is "read committed". I ran the psql command `show transaction_isolation;` in the related database.

Comment: So you have a commited update event showing the change STARTED -> PAID while the change itself remains uncommited? Is PAID -> STARTED permitted and would in that case event updates be generated?

Comment: @briadeus Exactly. If you refer to our application logic with "permitted", then no. Once a contract is PAID it is not allowed to go back to STARTED. Database-wise it is allowed, as the status is only a string-column (`@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`). But maybe @Greg is right and something else is overwriting the entity with an old value. I will have to dig through all the related code over the holidays. Thank you guys, I will keep you updated!

Comment: It took some time now but I think I am narrowing down on the error. Somehow the "updatedAt" field of the contractentity gets updated, even if a user only does a GET on contracts (fetches contracts).  I think this is because on each login we create a login event in the database inside the same transaction where we get the contracts. I am now reading this to see if I can fix it: https://xebia.com/blog/why-did-hibernate-update-my-database/